# Not able to enter_text in webview calabash-android

Tags: calabash-android

I am new to calabash-android and I have been trying to enter the login page (webview) within the app.

I have reviewed several sites but I have not gotten any results.

The error that I get is:

> Timeout waiting for elements: webView css:'input[name=UserName]' (Calabash::Android::WaitHelpers::WaitError)

The code that I am using in calabash is:

```
When(/^I enter email$/) do
   enter_text "webView css:'input[name=UserName]'", "test@test.com"
do
```

I have the same issue trying to click on the button.

The HTML (within the page) of the form is:

```
<form role="form" action="/SSO/Productos" method="post" id="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="UserName" required="required" name="UserName"  placeholder="email">
        <span class="form-highlight"></span>
        <span class="form-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control2" id="Password" required="required" name="Password"   placeholder="Password">
        <span class="form-highlight"></span>
        <span class="form-bar"></span>
        <button id="submitbutton" type="submit" tabindex="3" class="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
        </button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: HTML <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserName" required="required" name="UserName" tabindex="1" placeholder="email">
<input type="password" class="form-control required" id="Password" required="required" name="Password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password">
<button id="submitbutton" type="submit" tabindex="3" class="btn btn-primary">
 Submit
</button>

Comment: Hi @RCMA - I tried to fix the formatting issue with your code snippet. I know it gets messy sometime, as the Stackoverflow markdown requires to indent code blocks by an additional 4+ spaces (or a tab). For reference, the markdown help is at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help - HTH (and welcome to SO)